# Can't import Apache Commons Jars

Tags: java, apache, jar, apache-commons

I'm trying to add the apache commons jar extensions to my project I copied my jar files in my project root. I also put these same files in my "Referenced Libraries" folder and when I run my app I'm getting the below error message.

To add the jars this is my process I right-click>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries>Add Jars

My error message Caused by: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils**

Comment: How are you running the app? From command line or IDE?

Comment: Can't import jars into what man? Netbeans? IntelliJ? Space?

Comment: for the future try using maven or other dependency management "tool" instead. It's better for handling dependencies.

Comment: @EddieB I'm using Eclipse with a ADT Plugin [link] (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: @hd1 I'm not running the app from the command line. I'm using Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are maybe missing a jar, try adding this jar to the classpath by doing just what you did before:

> right-click>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries>Add Jars
>
> Download this JAR:
>   http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm sorry let me rephrase the answer

Comment: @GuidoCelada Hi I added the above Jar file but in the Java Build Path when I click Libraries and then individually click on each jar file my **source attachment, javadoc location, native library location and are considered (None) and Access Rules has (No Restrictions)**

Comment: for the javadoc you can google "javadoc apache commons io" and 

Right Click the JAR file in Project Explorer -> Properties -> From the left pane choose Javadoc Location -> enter the URL of your jar documentation.