# Intellij cannot resolve symbol 'lang3' apache

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, apache-commons-lang3

I would like to use StringUtils and have downloaded the "apache commons jar" zip file, copied the unzipped jar file into a lib folder in my intellij project, and added it to Libraries and to the classpath (via Project Settings). Then I imported with

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

but intelliJ can't resolve 'lang3'. Does anyone have any advice? Note: similar questions exist on stack exchange, eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172653/cant-import-apache-commons-jars), but they're not quite the same issue and their solutions haven't helped.

FYI I downloaded the 'common-lang3/common-lang3.jar.zip' folder from [this website](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonlang3jar.htm).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpack the zip and add the extracted `common-lang3.jar` file to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) instead of the downloaded `common-lang3.jar.zip` file.

Here is the sample project: [HelloStringUtils.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1qd5ltzjzvm6g5/HelloStringUtils.zip?dl=1).

Result of the execution and import working:

[image: Hello working]

Dependency configuration screenshots:

- [module dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a03dl.png)
- [library contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAutO.png)
- [`StringUtils` class browsable in the library jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGiVu.png)

Comment: Hi, yes I did, but thanks and I've updated my question

Comment: @KMunro see the updated answer. Everything works fine.

Comment: @KMunro If it still doesn't work for you, the only way to get help would be to share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks! I noticed your jar had a different name and contents, so I copied that and it worked. Oddly, when I revisit the link in my post, from which I downloaded the original (clearly wrong) jar file, it is the correct file now. I've no idea why but thankyou.